# What does it mean "W/AudioFlinger( 34): write blocked for 70 msecs, 2236 delayed writes, thread "?

Tags: java, android, debugging, audio, xamarin.android

I have monodroid app which play few sounds in same time, there are many messges like this in log. What does it mean?

```
W/AudioFlinger(   34): write blocked for 84 msecs, 2153 delayed writes, thread 0xc658
W/AudioFlinger(   34): write blocked for 69 msecs, 2182 delayed writes, thread 0xc658
W/AudioFlinger(   34): write blocked for 76 msecs, 2205 delayed writes, thread 0xc658
W/AudioFlinger(   34): write blocked for 70 msecs, 2236 delayed writes, thread 0xc658
W/AudioFlinger(   34): write blocked for 73 msecs, 2269 delayed writes, thread 0xc658
W/AudioFlinger(   34): write blocked for 75 msecs, 2300 delayed writes, thread 0xc658
W/AudioFlinger(   34): write blocked for 70 msecs, 2325 delayed writes, thread 0xc658
W/AudioFlinger(   34): write blocked for 69 msecs, 2356 delayed writes, thread 0xc658
W/AudioFlinger(   34): write blocked for 75 msecs, 2386 delayed writes, thread 0xc658
W/AudioFlinger(   34): write blocked for 70 msecs, 2418 delayed writes, thread 0xc658
W/AudioFlinger(   34): write blocked for 80 msecs, 2445 delayed writes, thread 0xc658
W/AudioFlinger(   34): write blocked for 71 msecs, 2473 delayed writes, thread 0xc658
W/AudioFlinger(   34): write blocked for 90 msecs, 2498 delayed writes, thread 0xc658
W/AudioFlinger(   34): write blocked for 72 msecs, 2528 delayed writes, thread 0xc658
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means you should ignore those messages. :-)

Every message contains a *Process ID* (pid), which is the value within the parenthesis. Those messages are coming from pid 34; it's *highly unlikely* that your process is pid 34.

You can use `adb shell ps` to get a process listing.

For example, on my Nexus One, I see:

```
W/AudioFlinger(14104): write blocked for 172 msecs, 901 delayed writes, thread 0xea50
```

What's pid 14104?

```
$ adb shell ps | grep 14104
media     14104 1     23992  1996  ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/mediaserver
```

`/system/bin/mediaserver` is certainly not an app you should be overly concerned about. :-)

How do you determine the pid for your Mono for Android process? [By looking for the process startup message.](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/android_debug_log#Interesting_Messages) During process startup Android will list all `ContentProvider`s it's loading into the process. Of interest is the `__mono_init__` provider:

```
I/ActivityThread(  602): Pub TouchTest.TouchTest.__mono_init__: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
```

The above message comes from your Mono for Android process, so all further messages with pid 602 (in this case) will be messages from your app; you can freely ignore other pids.

Answer (score 3):

It might or it might not be something that you can ignore. The process that is outputting that message is indeed not your app but that doesn't mean the message is not caused by your app. Your application is communicating via Binder with AudioFlinger which resides in the mediaserver process so that is why the PID of the warning message is not the PID of your app. However the message might be because the AudioFlinger is requested to playback data faster than the audio data is actually supposed to be played back (based on samplerate, number of channels and the size of the buffer). If the app is using the AudioTrack class to write raw data (and that is done from multiple threads?) then probably the data is sent faster than it can be played back, so AudioFligner is "overloaded".

Comment: This should be marked as answer, because it actually answers the question "What does it mean?" without telling stories about "it's not your deal".

Answer (score 2):

After a quick Google-search, I found that `AudioFlinger` is the audio software implementation that provides the minimum required audio functions. It implements `AudioHardwareInterface`, which is basically the hardware abstraction layer that hides driver-specific audio implementations from the Android platform (see the image below).

[image]

The libraries that power the Android framework are allowed to log information to the logcat, just as developers are. Some devices log a ridiculous amount (i.e. the libraries that power Samsung devices, in my experience), while others will log very little. Either way, you shouldn't worry about these logs because they are specific to the internal workings of the Android operating system. They don't reflect any problems with your app. You can ignore them.

Comment: Actually AudioFlinger does not _implement_ AudioHardwareInterface, it talks to the HAL layer that implements AudioHardwareInterface, which can be a proprietary library. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes as Jnop said let's ignore it.
Let me share my experience that could be useful to some one.
We usually ignore these messages because it is not causing any issue to the functionality and android platform logs lot of information on kernel processes,libraries,application framework etc that may be useful for an API developer and not for a application developer.

If you develop an app with NDK the knowledge of native methods is obviously helps.

I would advice to understand the concept if require from the docs on MediaPlayback and MediaPlayer API.

1)http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html
2)what are the Key Classes
3)The best approach for MediaPlay back implementation
4)https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/s6Bqu3K20Ng

Also please share your experience on this if you have already implented. Because I strongly feel that they are known issues in Mediaplayer and Android development team may not be showing much interest on this for whatever reason.

You can click pause button to stop lengthy logged message and you can easily scroll in logcat window.